# How to use colnames() inside a function in R without it turning the numerical output into a character?

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

I wrote an `R` function that takes its input and outputs a dataframe. It worked as it should, however, when I tried to add another line to name the only column of the output dataframe, it failed.

For this, I tried to use `colnames()`.

The result of the failed operation is a `character` instead of the correct dataframe. 
Here's a little reproducible example that goes straight into the issue.

```
# Fake Data

numbers = rnorm(5)

# Functions ---------------------------------------------------------------

# Dataframe is generated correctly. 

print_df_right = function(my_input){
   number_df = data.frame(my_input)
}

foo = print_df_right(numbers)
foo # A correct, column-nameless dataframe
#>     my_input
#> 1  0.3379014
#> 2  0.5306519
#> 3  0.7689149
#> 4 -0.5548860
#> 5 -2.1199438


# Dataframe is ruined because colnames() turns it into a vector.
ruin_my_df = function(my_input){
   number_df = data.frame(my_input)
   colnames(number_df) = c("numbers")
}

foo = ruin_my_df(numbers)
foo # This was supposed to be a dataframe, but instead is a character.
#> [1] "numbers"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to return the dataset.  In the OP's function, it is returning the last expression i.e. assigning the column names to 'numbers' and as there is only one column,  the column name 'numbers' got returned

```
ruin_my_df_corrected <- function(my_input){
   number_df <- data.frame(my_input)
   colnames(number_df) <- c("numbers")
   number_df
   }
```

Or instead of creating multiple statements, it can be a single one

```
ruin_my_df_corrected <- function(my_input){
        setNames(data.frame(my_input), "numbers")

  }
```

Comment: Now that's fast.

Comment: Any idea why is that a necessity, @akrun? What am I missing?

Comment: @MasonBeau  It is evaluating the last statement or expression which is the `colnames`. Or else you can use `setNames(data.frame(my_input), "numbers")`

Comment: Simpler is `data.frame(numbers = my_input)`. Simplest?

Comment: @RuiBarradas yes, you are right.  I was thinking that the OP want to also pass an object

Comment: Like `names_right_df <- function(my_input) data.frame(numbers = my_input)
`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas i meant `function(my_input, numobj) setNames(data.frame(my_input), numobj)`

Comment: OK, got it, I was thinking about the examples in the question.

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner:

```
names_right_df <- function(my_input) data.frame(numbers = my_input)

names_right_df(numbers)
#     numbers
#1 -0.7654521
#2  1.0077708
#3  1.1608095
#4  1.1352666
#5 -1.0030617
```